# MS Access Foreign Key Record Fill Too Fast

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-office

I have a problem with one of my forms in my MS Access database, and strangely it's the only form that has this problem.

The form has a typical Master/Detail structure, with the subform tied to a table. The subform record source includes a foreign key that pulls information from another table and populates the rest of the fields based on the key value. This foreign key is a Material number that defines a specific object in an inventory, and the other fields in the subform show details of this object.

Example from Signs table:

Material number: 116063175

StorageBin: A116

Material Description: Stop Sign

Dimensions: 48x48

All of this information is contained in the same table, but the form is for a table that is used to fill in what signs are on a particular road (stops, speed limits, etc.)

On all my other forms, when I type in the material number and shift focus anywhere else, the rest of the forms will fill in automatically. This process works here too, but for some reason Access wants to try to fill in the rest of the field data before I have finished typing the material number. I'll type "1" and access will throw an error that it cannot find a matching record in the Signs table in the foreign key's table. After rejecting the error twice, the data entry can resume as normal, which is also strange.

I hope I've been clear enough, this is my first time asking a question here.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Tried re-building the form, same issue. Built another form similar but without my multiple comboboxes, didn't have the issue! Could this be due to underlying requery code in the Afterupdate event of my comboboxes? I have a cascading combobox setup on the form, could data entry be triggering a requery?

Edit2: for the time being, a fix that I am using is to make the material number and quantity (the two important fields for this form) into text boxes outside the subform, that the user can edit then place in the subform with a button click, which is coded as so:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
If Me!PrimaryRoadInventorySubform.Form.Dirty Then
        Me!PrimaryRoadInventorySubform.Form.Dirty = False
End If
Me!PrimaryRoadInventorySubform.SetFocus
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
Me!PrimaryRoadInventorySubform.Form!MaterialNumber = MaterialNumtxt
Me!PrimaryRoadInventorySubform.Form!Quantity = Quantitytxt
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have limittolist property set to Yes? Do you have any code in OnChange event?

Comment: @dbmitch: The only code present in this form is in the AfterUpdate events for two comboboxes on the form (that have nothing to do with this material number object; they help to specify information that is stored in the table the form is based on. The code just requeries the comboboxes). I don't have any limit to list properties in my form set to Yes, except a combobox that isn't tied to the subform. And there is no limit to list property for a subform that I can see...